# Extract number from a string C

Tags: c, string

I have a bunch of strings structured like this one.
I want to extract them, put them into an array or int.

For example:

- DATA:PHONENUMBER123456AGE7890
- TEL:123
- TEL1A:123456
- TEL2B:123456

I need to extract:

```
DATA PHONENUMBER 123456 AGE 7890
TEL 123
TEL1A 123456
TEL2B 123456
```

And use printf to output these values

```
a=DATA b=PHONENUMBER c=123456 d=AGE e=7890
a=TEL b=123
a=TEL1A b=123456
a=TEL2B b=123456
```

I used the following code, but it was not appropriate.
This worked for 123abc but if the input is abc123, how do I process the letters and then the digits.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 


int main(void)
{
  char buf[BUFSIZ];
  char *p;
  long int i;

  printf ("Enter a number: ");

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
  {
    i = strtol(buf, &p, 10);

    if (buf[0] != '\n' && (*p == '\n' || *p == '\0'))
      printf ("Valid number of %ld entered\n", i); 
    else  printf ("The number was %d, followed by %s\n", i, p);
  }  

  return(0);
}

/*
 * Program output:
   Enter a number: 123abc
   The number was 123, followed by abc
 *
 */
```

I tried to extract them, but I really could not write it.
The program uses C.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: `man scanf` -- specifically you probably want `sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)`

Comment: According to my knowledge, if you know the occurrence of Alphabets and Numbers already, u can use sscanf. If you don't know, you have to write a function for that.

Comment: If you actually already have the numbers and don't need use input (mean you don't need `sscanf`) you could use `int atoi(const char *nptr)` from `stdlib.h` . Please have a look to the manual pages of both `sscanf()` and `atoi()`

Comment: _I tried to extract them_: then you should be able to show us your code-

Comment: I have improved the question, you see, is this question correct? If it is correct, expect you to vote for me to help me, thank you ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sscanf and scansets the sub-strings can be extracted. The scanset `%79[^:]` will scan up to 79 characters that are not `:` and `%79[0-9]` will scan up to 79 characters that are digits. The `%n` specifier will capture the number of characters processed by the scan. This allow the sub-scans to start where the last scan left off.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char a[80] = "";
    int c = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int each = 0;
    int span = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    char text[][80] = {
        "DATA:PHONENUMBER123456AGE7890"
        , "TEL:123"
        , "TEL1A:123456"
        , "TEL2B:123456"
    };

    while ( 1 == sscanf ( text[each], " %79[^:]:%n", a, &span)) {//scan up to : then scan :
        printf ( "\n%s\n", text[each]);//print full element of text array
        offset = span;
        printf ( "text before : = %s\n", a);
        do {
            if ( 1 == ( result = sscanf ( text[each] + offset, " %79[^0-9]%n", a, &span))) {// scan non-numbers
                offset += span;
                printf ( "\ttext = %s\n", a);
            }
            if ( 1 == ( result = sscanf ( text[each] + offset, " %79[0-9]%n", a, &span))) {//scan numbers
                offset += span;
                printf ( "\tnumber text = %s\n", a);
                if ( 1 == sscanf ( a, "%d", &c)) {//scan text number to int
                    printf ( "\tnumber value = %d\n", c);
                }
            }
        } while ( result != EOF);//loop until end of text[each]
        each++;//next element in text array
        if ( each >= 4) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you!
I saw the output, but I do not know how to assign value

Comment: Thank you!
Why is my vote negative, how can i modify the problem?

Comment: I have improved the question, you see, is this question correct? If it is correct, expect you to vote for me to help me, thank you ~